# Coq Section: require typeclass instance

Tags: typeclass, coq

```
Require Import Relations RelationClasses.

Section MySection.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable R : relation A.
  (* ... *)
End MySection.
```

How could I require `R` to be a partial order?

Comment: Congrats! This is the 1000th Coq question on Stackoverflow!

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `Context` syntax, see The Coq Reference manual, [§20.4](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual023.html#SectionContext):

> To ease the parametrization of developments by type classes, we provide a new way to introduce variables into section contexts, compatible with the implicit argument mechanism. The new command works similarly to the `Variables` vernacular (see 1.3.1), except it accepts any binding context as argument.

Example:

```
From Coq Require Import RelationClasses.

Generalizable Variable A eqA R.

Section MySection.
  Context `{PO : PartialOrder A eqA R}.
  (* ... *)
End MySection.
```

Comment: And for those who wonder about the backquote and `Generalizable Variable`, see [Implicit generalization in the Ref. Man.](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#implicit-generalization)